# Should I use 404 Not found or 410 Gone for a bulletin board system, when a topic is deleted?

Tags: http, seo, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, http-status-code-410

I'm creating a bulletin board system, and now I'm implementing a 'delete topic' feature for admins. If someone opens the deleted topic, the server cannot find it, so it must be 404. On the other hand, the topic has existed sometime, so I must use 410. Implementing the 410 would require a new table called deleted_topics, and so would require more space. However, 410 I think is better for search engines. What do you think? Should I use 404 or 410?

## 404 Not found

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

## 410 Gone

> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be considered permanent. Clients with link editing capabilities SHOULD delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. If the server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD be used instead. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.
>
> The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is intentionally unavailable and that the server owners desire that remote links to that resource be removed. Such an event is common for limited-time, promotional services and for resources belonging to individuals no longer working at the server's site. It is not necessary to mark all permanently unavailable resources as "gone" or to keep the mark for any length of time -- that is left to the discretion of the server owner.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Showing a 410 requires a little more effort than a 404 because to know it's a 410 you need to maintain at least a "ghost" of the former page in your database. If this is not a problem to you, I'd consider the 410 "better" and "friendlier" because it presents more information. If you don't want to be hassled with maintaining a graveyard in your database, then 404 is acceptable too, of course.

I don't like Alohci's approach of redirecting to a different page. The end result looks like the user ended up on the "input new topic" page (or whatever) by accident. This works, but I think a preferable solution would be to create a **custom 410 page** (or 404 page, if you don't want to support 410) with specific information for the case at hand. I.e. your 410 shouldn't just say "gone", it should say "this post has been deleted, here's a link to similar posts or a link to create a new post". Your "404" wouldn't have quite as much information available but it could still offer a subset of such information and links.

I guess the "custom 410 page" comes close in appearance to "redirecting with 301" but an important difference is that robotic users of your site (of which there are *many*!) will get the more accurate status, and know to purge the old link from their crawl index – this will ultimately save them and you some unnecessary traffic.

Comment: A 410 response is a good way to give a reason for why a resource is no longer available.

Comment: I've deleted my response as it clearly wasn't helping, but... Why would a search engine not remove a "301 Moved Permanently" page from its index?

Comment: 301 says, "this is not a working link but if you follow this redirect you get some kind of result anyway". A greedy crawler will take anything it can get its furry little claws on. 410 says, "nothing to see here, go away and stop bothering!" SE algorithms are the subject of much debate but it's reasonable to assume that the stronger message will be more likely to discourage the crawler.

Answer (score 4):

I think the correct way to do this is by sending the 410 Gone for some time and after a few weeks/months to switch to 404 Not found. Of course, it is for you to decide if that is worth the amount of time and effort.

Comment: This question is tagged SEO and that's not a good idea from an SEO viewpoint. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Since you tagged your question 'SEO' I'm assuming you want the best SEO answer. If there are any backlinks (coming from outside sites) to your deleted topic all the 'link juice' will be lost with 404 and 410 status.

Instead you should definitely create some 301 redirects which point to the root of the site, the root of the forum, or a related category. You will thus preserve the link juice and you get to decide which pages of your site will benefit most.

Comment: So the goal of providing correct and up to date information is at odds with the goal of generating lots of page views. This explains a lot of what's wrong with the Internet. * sigh *.

Comment: @Carl. Yes it does. But lets face it, HTTP status codes are horribly broken all over the internet. Worrying about their purity ahead of practicality is pointless.

Comment: That's exactly why I try to discourage people from inserting even more breakage into the 'net. Truth is good, lies are bad; it's that simple.

Comment: It's that simple only in a fanatical, literal religious context. In real life you have to balance out truth and self interest. You just have to find where you stand in that balance but at least one should be educated about the options.

Comment: And although it's true that the page is gone, it's also true that you want to redirect your users to a more useful place. If a store closes down they sometimes put a sign on the door for the closes similar store. That's a service to the users.

Comment: Yes, and it's a service that can be suitably presented on a 410 page without deceiving the user.